# Check to see is GridViewRow cell is null in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB project I'm working on where I have to break the GridView down to each row and examine a specific cell. How do I go about checking to see if there is a null value or not? The following code results in the error message

"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index"

I've checked the cell count for the GridViewRow variable "row" and it comes up at 5, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Protected Sub grdProduct_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdProduct.RowDataBound

    ' Grey out expired products
    Dim row As GridViewRow
    row = e.Row

    Dim incomingStatus As String
    If row.Cells(5).Text.ToString() <> vbNull Then
        incomingStatus = row.Cells(5).Text.ToString()
    Else
        incomingStatus = ""
    End If
```

I modified the code to check the cell count first and it is still coming back with the exact same error.

```
    If row.Cells.Count > 5 And row.Cells(5).Text.ToString() <> vbNull Then
        incomingStatus = row.Cells(5).Text.ToString()
    Else
        incomingStatus = ""
    End If
```

FINAL EDIT

Modifying the code like so fixed the problem. Thanks guys:

```
    If row.Cells.Count > 5 Then
        If row.Cells(5).Text.ToString() <> vbNull Then
            incomingStatus = row.Cells(5).Text.ToString()
        Else
            incomingStatus = ""
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: If cell count is 5, then max of the index would be 4 for 0-based arrays.

Comment: **.ToString() will _never_ return vbNull,** unless you override it in a custom method to do so on purpose. Instead, you'll either get an exception because the object calling .ToString() was nothing (Object reference not set to instance of object) or you'll get an empty string or other output that is not equal to vbNull.

Comment: Also, why on earth would you call .ToString() from a .Text property? The .Text property is _already_ a string. Calling .ToString() works out to a no-op.

Comment: Finally, I'm not sure about grid cells, but a lot of control types have the .Text property designed such that it will never be null, and it's always safe to compare to an empty string instead.

Comment: Good catch. This is code someone else wrote that I'm touching up. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've checked the cell count for the GridViewRow variable "row" and it
>   comes up at 5, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

`row.Cells(5)` returns the 6th Cell, not the 5th since indices are 0 based in .NET. But the `Count` property returns the actual number of cells.

The same is true for `GridView.Rows`.

```
GridView1.Rows(9)
```

returns the 10th `GridViewRow`.